Loading Audio Text Tracks programmatically
From the WebVTT API docs

A text track and cues can be defined in a file using the WebVTT File
Format, and then associated with a particular <video> element using
the <track> element.
Alternatively you can add a TextTrack to a media element in JavaScript
using HTMLMediaElement.addTextTrack(), and then add individual VTTCue
objects to the track with TextTrack.addCue().

I have a vtt file and I'm using new Audio(src); with no <audio> element in the html. Is it not possible to add a text track with a vtt file without an actual <audio> element or do I have to parse the vtt file myself and call addCue for each cue defined in the file?
I'm not using <audio> elements because I need to load about 20 audio files (with vtt files) and play them in a specific order. Maybe I could have one <audio> element and reuse it?

You can programmatically create the <track> element.
const a = new Audio('woot.webm');
const t = document.createElement('track');
t.src = 'subtitles.webvtt';
a.appendChild(t);


Maybe I could have one  element and reuse it?

Yes, that's what I would do, for multiple reasons.  The biggest of which is that you must do this if you want iOS compatibility.  Otherwise, iPhones will refuse to play subsequent tracks one after the other.
